# Websocket Reverse Tunnel

Tags: websocket

I am trying to see if there is any existing websocket implementation that will solve the problem described below. I did take a look at websockify but from what I understand it may not solve the problem I am looking at.

Lets say I have 2 hosts, Host-A and Host-B. Host-A, a websocket client, will set up websocket connection to Host-B. Host-B should now be able to connect to SSH Server on Host-A over this websocket connection. Further to this, Host-A should be able to setup reverse tunnel for not just SSH but possibly other protocols too on the same websocket connection.

1. Could this be achieved?
2. Are there any existing implementations that does anything close to this?
3. What possibly needs to be done to support this scenario with websockets?

Answer (score 3):

even if the question is old, you can try to reade the documentation of node-reverse-wstunnel, this is a nodejs module that implement websocket tunnel and reverse websocket tunnel.

The link of the gitHub project repository is:
https://github.com/MDSLab/node-reverse-wstunnel

The follow link is the nodejs module:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-reverse-wstunnel